# Splitting a Quoted Search String with Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to split a string into searchable terms.  I need it to

- split on spaces and single quotes (ignoring single character, non-quoted results)
- return quoted phrases without the quotes

So if I'm applying it to: **"quoted phrase" single words**
It would return

- quoted phrase
- single
- words

Here's what I have so far (in Javascript), but I have to have to strip the quotes out separately.

```
var searchArray = temp.match(/"[^"]*"|[^\s']{2,}/g);
for (index in searchArray)
    searchArray[index] = searchArray[index].replace(/"/g, '');
```

Is there any way to do this using only one regular expression?

Comment: Consider this input text: `"double quotes" 'single quotes' "Mixed 'quotes' here" 'The "other" way'`  Also, what do you do if the "single character" to ignore is a quote?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't care about single quotes, but I wanted the results not to be possessive.  For the sake of this discussion, we can ignore single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work but I'm not sure I've covered all cases. I'm not sure it'll work in IE 5, but that may not worry you; it works in IE 6 and all other browsers I've tried. It also strips leading and trailing whitespace from matches inside quotes:

```
var regex = /("?)\s*\b(\S[^\1]*?)\b\s*\1/g;
var str = '"quoted phrase " single "quoted" words " yes "';
var res;

while ( (res = regex.exec(str)) ) {
    alert(res[2]);
}
```

Comment: That looks like that'll do what I was looking for.  Thank you very much!  I'd like to mark your answer as useful, but I don't have enough reputation yet.